# strong stability for the wave equation

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, oc.optimization-and-control, sp.spectral-theory, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider the $n-$dimensional wave equation
$$z_{tt}=\Delta z + k(x) z - \epsilon {1}_\omega z_t, \; in \; \Omega\times (0,T)$$

where $\omega\subset \Omega.$ Can I have $z(t) \to 0,$ as $t\to+\infty$ for all $k\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ by choosing $\epsilon?$